# Using Powershell to identify user ID's with mixed case (upper and lower)

Tags: powershell, uppercase, lowercase

I have a csv with student ID's that were created incorrectly. They have Upper First Initial, lower 2nd First Initial, Upper Last Initial.  I need to be able to find these within the csv that contains about 4,500 User ID's and likely eventually all that are in AD.  I know how to rename and correct them. I just need to quickly locate them without manually reading and locating each name individually.  I'm sure it has to do with finding an array [A-Z]^[a-z]^[A-Z] I have just been unsuccessful.
Any assistance on this will be very helpful!

```
Import-Module ac*
# Student
Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Student, OU=PPS, DC=ad, DC=ppsnet" -Properties GivenName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, SamAccountName, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, department |

`Where {$_.department -like "*KG*" -and  $_.SamAccountName -cmatch '(?:[A-Z][a-z][A-Z].*3)'} | Select GivenName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, SamAccountName, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, department |

Export-csv .\Output\Student\Kinders.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of the dataset as-is, and how you would like it to appear?  Also, can you provide a snippet of what you tried so far, and why it didn't work (actual output)?  [These](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) details are very important to help you [effectively](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  ;)

Comment: The data as is, is - Susie Jones SuJones1234
I need to find these user ID's that are like this so that I can rename them to   SJones1234

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned, there is not enough information yet to provide a more detailed answer, but you might try something like this

```
$names = @'
John jacob Jingleheimer
elaine Hall Ramos
James Morrison dixon
Margie Lee Gonzales
'@.Split("`n")

$names | % {
    if ($_.Split(' ') | ? {$_[0] -cmatch '^[a-z]'}) {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
```

here is an alternate method

```
$names | ? {$_ -cnotmatch '(?:[A-Z].*){3}'}
```

Comment: I have a standard script that I used to get student AD Information and it works fine extracting to .csv the 4,500 Kindergarten accounts.  Then I added an -and statement to my "Where" and it doesn't like that.  I get an error that says Where-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'and'
Here is my modified script adding the -and

Where {$_.department -like "*KG*"} -and { $_.SamAccountName -match "^[^A-Z]^[a-z]^[A-Z]"*3} | Select GivenName, Surname, EmployeeNumber, SamAccountName, PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName, department |
Export-csv .\Output

Comment: I figured out the - and in my Where-Object, but it still isn't identifying/finding the SamAccountName with the mixed upper and lower case user ID's

Comment: first, you are using `-match`. what you want to be using is `-cmatch` for case sensitive. second, `^` in regex (when used outside of `[]`) means 'beginning of the string' so it makes no sense to have any more than the first one at the beginning. check my edit to see if you could use `-cnotmatch` and that regular expression.

Comment: I made the suggested modification to my script
Where {$_.department -like "*KG*" -and  $_.SamAccountName -cnotmatch '(?:[A-Z].*){3}'} but produces the same results.  
I need ONLY accounts that match upper,lower,upper i.e.  SuJones and to ignore any names that are SJones

Comment: `$_.SamAccountName -cmatch '^[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]'` should work. you can see why it is difficult to guess what you are trying to do when we are not given sample data

Comment: I do apologize that I didn't tell you specifically I needed to find SuJones and ignore SJones  I had mentioned it in an above comment.

Comment: This was the winning Solution!
Where {$_.department -like "*KG*" -and  $_.SamAccountName -cmatch '(?:[A-Z][a-z][A-Z].*3)'}
THANK YOU! for your assistance!  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Where {$*.department -like "*KG*" -and  $*.SamAccountName -cmatch '(?:[A-Z][a-z][A-Z].*3)'}
This exported only the user accounts that had Uppercase,Lowercase,Uppercase user names  i.e.  SuJones and it ignored  SJones.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the where clause as shown below.

```
Where {($_.department -like "*KG*") -and ($_.SamAccountName -cmatch '(?:[A-Z][a-z][A-Z].*3)')}
```

Comment: Where {($_.department -like "*KG*") -and  ($_.SamAccountName -cmatch '(?:[A-Z][a-z][A-Z].*3)')}